# How to wrap wp_list_pages($args); with div and ul elements?

Tags: wordpress

How can I wrap `wp_list_pages` with a `div`?

I am using

```
<?php wp_list_pages($args); ?>
```

and trying to wrap these elements with:

```
<div id="menu"><ul></ul></div>
```

I can't use simple HTML in the template because I don't want to see it empty on other sites where there are no items in `wp_list_pages`.

I was trying to use `list_before` and `list_after` but it was wrapping every element of the list, whereas I need it to wrap all the items.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited the formatting and grammar of your post to hopefully make it easier to understand and get you a quicker solution to your problem. It might help to show a screenshot of what the page looked like in your attempt, or share the code where you were using `list_before` and `list_after` so others can see what you've tried.